# Xcode 6 not running the test target when testing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

After upgrading to Xcode 6, I noticed that the macros I defined for the Test target were not working. After further examination, it seems like Xcode 6 is not running the test target, but rather the actual app target, when testing. Has anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions on how to fix it?